# DataGridView implemented with ITypedList is not working

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

The DataSource is a class object , this class implements ITypedList list to generate the DataGridViewColumns, these columns will be assigned to DataGridView while assigning as below code snippet. , and these list of columns will be generated through GetItemProperties method of ITypedList.

The C# code snippet as below.

***DataGridView1.DataSource = ClassObject.***

This is perfectly working fine during initial load , once DataGridView loaded i have functionality to add columns at runtime ,But DataGrid is not showing newly added column,so debugged to see whats happening i am able to see the newly added column in the ClassObject as well as in DataSource.ListColumns, but not in DataGridView1.Columns.List. i digged further i have changed the code snippet as below to make it work.

The C# code snippet as below.

***DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ClassObject;***

if i am making null before assigning ClassObject to the DataGridView.DataSource then DataGridView1 showing newly added column at runtime , but i have filter functionality like excel this is not working due to DataGridView1.DataSource = null; due to this DataGridView lost all filtered history ,so i need to remove this code for filter functionality to work. Please suggest me what i need to do to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.
Ravindra

Comment: [How to: Implement the ITypedList Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-itypedlist-interface). I suggest to set your class object as the DataSource of a BindingSource anyway, then use the BindingSource as the DataSource of the DataGridView.

Comment: Hi Jimi, i tried this scenario also , this scenario also not working...

Comment: If you have code that's not working, you need to post the code. We cannot help you debug thin air.

Comment: Please, do not post code in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61750654/edit)  your question, posting all the code necessary to replicate the problem, as recommended in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you didn't take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so you didn't read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Take a look at these sources of information on how the Site works.

Comment: As per the link provided by you , if i comment this line of code .dataGridView1.DataSource = null; in the sort event handler then sorting of the columns will not be done, i wanted to achieve sorting of DataGridView columns with out making this.DataSource = null;

Comment: There's no need at all to set `DataSource = null;`. As already mentioned, use a BindingSource (i.e., set the DataSource of a BindingSource to your collection of objects, then set `DataGridView.DataSource = [Your BindingSource];`). You can then use your object's methods to filter or sort the collection or use the BindingSource [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter) and [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.sort) properties. You still haven't produced any code that can be tested.

Comment: One thing i wanted to tell that i am not using datatable to filter and sorting , i am using class object as datasource only since i need to show 10 million records in single view , based on this class object still i can do filter and sorting but i am using Advance DataGridView to do the filters like in Excel , if i use BindingSource as you said as datasource , once i filtered then i cannot able to see complete entries in the popup filter , i am able to see only selected entries in the popup filter and clear filter menu item in the filter popup screen.

Comment: i need to share  3 to 4 calsses code , i will do it if this query still not enough to give a suggestion to fix this issue.